# How to convert this js file to typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am trying to convert this javascript file to typescript.
However I am getting an error on the onClick function as below :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Popover } from 'antd';
import A from './A';
import B from './B';

class Demo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    visible: false,
    btnName : "Button A",
    selected : false,
  }

  hide = () => {
    this.setState({
      visible: false,
    });
  };

  onClick = () =>{
      this.state.selected ? this.setState({btnName : "Button A"}) : this.setState({btnName : "Button B"});
      this.state.selected ? this.setState({selected : false}) : this.setState({selected :true });
      this.state.visible ? this.setState({visible : false}) : this.setState({visible : true})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Popover
        content={ 
        <>
        <A />
        <B />
        </>
        }
        trigger="click"
        onClick ={this.onClick}
        visible={this.state.visible}
        placement="topLeft"
      >
        
          <button
              className= {this.state.selected ? "style1": "style2"}
              onClick= {this.onClick}
            >
                      <span>{this.state.btnName}</span>          
         </button>  
      </Popover>
    );
  }
}

export default Demo;
```

**{
"message": "Type '{ children: Element; content: Element; trigger: string; onClick: () => void; visible: boolean; placement: "topLeft"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PopoverProps & RefAttributes'.\n  Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PopoverProps & RefAttributes'.",
}**

This is the above error message,
I am new to typescript, could anyone help??

Comment: add types! Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Googling `is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PopoverProps & RefAttributes` gave me this SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/60008055/1501613. Haven't been using React but sounds likely to be related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `onClick` in `Popover` component. You need remove it and use `onClick` on child component of `Popover` (button)