# what is the Intrinsic Attributes in react inferred by typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I can see a lot of SO questions - me too - referring to errors based on matching with `type 'IntrinsicAttributes'`

for example when you trying to pass a `prop` e.g `<Greet foo="hello" />` to component without defining it in the component prop type it will immediately shows an error saying :

```
Type '{ foo: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'
```

I guessed `key` is one of this Intrinsic Attributes that when I pass it typescript will not produce this kind of error

I need to know what is react component Intrinsic Attributes and if there a list of it?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#attribute-type-checking and https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1ce3303b425014edc25aa59815b51896d8e0dd21/types/react/index.d.ts#L3141 (coming from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/1ce3303b425014edc25aa59815b51896d8e0dd21/types/react/index.d.ts#L127-L133)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969756/not-assignable-to-type-intrinsicattributes-intrinsicclassattributes-react-js)

Answer (score 0):

In React, intrinsic attributes are a special kind of attribute that have specific meanings within React rendering system, beyond their typical use in HTML. These attributes play important roles in reconciliation and DOM manipulation.

Some examples of intrinsic attributes:

key: Used for efficiently identifying and updating elements in lists.
className: Used for applying CSS classes (replaces "class" in React to avoid JavaScript conflicts).
style: Used for applying inline styles to elements.
ref: Used for creating references to DOM elements or component instances.

These attributes are essential for effective React development, as they help React manage the virtual DOM and ensure efficient updates to the actual DOM.