# Type '...' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here's the situation:

```js
type StringKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type BaseProps = {
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
}

type StringVersion = BaseProps & {
  data: string[];
  displayKey: never;
}

type ObjectVersion<TData> = BaseProps & {
  data: Pick<TData, StringKeys<TData>>[];
  displayKey: StringKeys<TData>
}

type Combo<TData = void> = TData extends Record<string, unknown> ? ObjectVersion<TData> : StringVersion;

const BaseComponent = <TData,>(props: Combo<TData>) => (
  <>base stuff</>
);
```

1. This works

```js
type WrapperProps<TData> = Combo<TData> & {};

const WorkingWrapper = <TData,>(props: WrapperProps<TData>) => {
  return <BaseComponent<TData> {...props} />
}
```

2. Contrived Example - Wrapper component is just slighly modifying provided values before passing the prop on...

```js
type WrapperProps<TData> = Combo<TData> & {};

const WrapperComponent = <TData,>(props: WrapperProps<TData>) => {
  const { width } = props;
  const myWidth = width! + 1;
  return (
    <div style={{width: myWidth}}>
      <BaseComponent<TData> {...props} width={myWidth} />
     // ^----------^ error
    </div>
  )
}
```

TS ERROR - BaseComponent

```
Type 'Combo<TData> & { width: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Combo<TData>'.
  Type 'Combo<TData> & { width: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.(2322)
```

3. Destructuring without any modification doesn't seem to work either...

```js
type WrapperProps<TData> = Combo<TData> & {};

const DestructuringWrapperComponent = <TData,>({ width, ...props}: WrapperProps<TData>) => {
  return (
    <div style={{width}}>
      <BaseComponent<TData> width={width} {...props} />
    // ^----------^ error
    </div>
  )
}
```

TS ERROR - BaseComponent

```
Type '{ width: number | undefined; } & Omit<WrapperProps<TData>, "width">' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Combo<TData>'.
  Type '{ width: number | undefined; } & Omit<WrapperProps<TData>, "width">' is not assignable to type 'Combo<TData>'.(2322)
```

I've been staring at this for longer than I'd care to admit. Can someone please help me understand why spreading props without any others satisfies React's expected type (#1) but including any props independently suddenly violates the "IntrinsicAttributes" type (#2 & #3)?

[Example TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AocmATzCTgGUYpgA7AcwGklqBnAHgAqAPjgBeOAG9ycOAG1OcNnADWPCJjiCAugC4tC7XCQAPGElYATXnF7M27OAH44i-ayQA3JFAoBfOTVqDS1tCipaegAhFF4kAAUcMBsJaVkAd2BLGAALJ3cAVxAAIx8KWRykYHYcmHy4ViLS33I-Sho6RnsOADUfXmAIVnE4GLjEiGS4ADIpGThLFBgUfTsWDjkw+ctgXjAAGxRqbmp3LzLW9si4AHligCskDD6oAaGhABEllFEJMYSkjZZmkFt99PFgGgVJ9vgAaLrrLg8ASCL7LYTCTblBa7A5HE76JiIk4otE-S4RToAYVwxQgMOWI08ECyvy0ZOMZgs1kQT2gln4awc8IKrBUrAg6VYohcd0ez36g1YDJ+cEJ3XYLzerHCaCGdlGsSQNPAQws8AkKthwgAFGBAfoTXSVcIAJTiUQ2+b8YTFI22GAFTCYfgAemE5FdV06AHUoCgwHQoBNki6Rk76ajvqJgX5wqHQ3AAJKaYAwfA2FD7fZwe4FA17IgoSxwXI4Ao1eFluDpaAqXhOch61gGmN9hxxhNJkZW232ya8fSTxM+FOk7PusSiEFEQNQYb8f4myAeVgwNOSAB01-nyT8cHDFILcBpZ5Y3hbAFETChwPt6AAtHAy7TnqpqnvAuy1vW8C8Ps1Q5Ps1BwCAEA7Jg1AOHA86eFkSAtp4VYFEgNilJg0D0GAsQDBwraVNhSRwEMQ76vAIE+MeZpnjOWbLNadoOsB8YrsmgIupu27zMOBqSD2WS5HA94SLevDYtJ8AgNQMbyTkIyZNkOQAIRwAA1HAACM2K7gU+5wF6siyPwOyeAG1D-mIkiSPpuT6Jp2kGX4fgRg5DmHkanEQRe16Xip97eTkHl+Tp96PiFYbOcFcBRm05DPp+3jDHWBqWCRzAFBgNlYZYEAkaw+CwUgSB4DAEA9n20UsSO8AfKVUDlXuE7CUmEXmjxZL8bJ8XwtFsVLkNq5ibxPwSXMsjWbZ9mhc5rnuZ58WBZlaVHrgJ7mmm8UeftUgzYCKWHXA6XAJ4mXZeQQA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969756/not-assignable-to-type-intrinsicattributes-intrinsicclassattributes-react-js)

Comment: @JoeLissner Eh, not really. I seem to be meeting all of the expected properties, and yet still running into TS errors. I tried a few things from that thread and none of them improved this situation.

Comment: you're right, this is different. I am not sure of the answer, but also curios. I created a smaller example that I believe re-creates the same root issue in a more concise way: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwsAFgSwHYHMA8AVKAXigFcMBrDOAdwwD4ioBvAKCiggC4o8BuFgL4sWoSFACiAGwDOEfA2IEIAD2AQMAE2lRpwAE6YsUAPyxEydNnlRu8JKkP8WAMzIBjYGjgYoa3fIAKJigAOjC9CF0oAW4pWXkASmY2KDdvKOo4PXJpWJk5PAVk9nYwkIjdABoUoSEXd09vX0jgACZA4IhK0PCW6Lz4wqTWdjSMKI04SIxgAHUs8gGCopGSsorgapKOGsFhIA